# Como substituir valores de uma string apartir de todos valores de um array?

Tags: php, array, string

Boa tarde pessoal, bem o problema é o seguinte..
Tenho uma string com nome x, e tenho dois arrays, nome e valor.
no for percorro ambos arrays onde identifico se na string X tem algum campo igual a $nome, se tiver substituo por $valor,
Tem alguma maneira de quando executado ele substitua e salve em uma string unica todos campos alterado? Codigo de exemplo abaixo:
Obs a string esta como array entao ela substitui de um em um os valores.

```
    $valor = array('1', '2');
    $nome = array('valor1', 'valor2');
    $x = "Esse é meu valor1 e meu valor2";
    for ($i=0; $i<$cc; ++$i) {

    $string[$i] = str_replace($nome[$i], $valor[$i], $x);
    echo $string[$i];
    echo "<br />";


}
```

Resposta que eu quero = " Esse é meu 1 e meu 2";
  Resposta que sai do jeito que o código esta = " Esse é meu 1 e meu valor2"
                                                " Esse é meu valor1 e meu 2"

Edit: Pessoal os valores que coloquei ali era para simplificação do problema, o $nome e $valor são dinamicos, podem ter N valores, $cc é o numero de elementos que compoem ambos arrays

Edit 2: Desculpem não ter sido mais claro,  a questão que estou tentando resolver é essa, eu tenho string com nome Ex: "Componente + Custo gerais", o $nome é o nome de cada componente, ex: $nome('Componente','Custo gerais'), tenho inputs que são gerados dinamicamente, eu to resgatando desses inputs o valor digitado e o id do componente que dps pego o nome no banco de dados,assim para cada componente(cada $nome) tenho um valor, o que eu realmente quero é por exemplo, ele vai pegar o arrays de nome e substituir com o valor correspondente do array $valor( que o i$ representaria a posição de ambos no array)

Edit 3: Tenho os valores 0=>10,1=>20  no array $valor, e  0 =>Custos, 1=>Gastos no array $nome, e uma string com nome "Custos - Gastos", pelo i$ no for substituiria ambas, e ficaria o valor final da string "10 - 20", é ae que eu quero chegar, ja que ele esta gerando atualmente "10 - Gastos " e em sequencia "Custos - 20".

O codigo : https://paste.ofcode.org/UnbrtXVGFE75N6QzizXbuM

Comment: obrigatóriamente vc precisa desses dois arrays?? Montar um único array multidimencional não resolveria?? do tipo `$valor = array('valor1' => '1', 'valor2' = '2');`, e ai em vez do for vc utilizar assim: ` $x = "Esse é meu {$valor['valor1']} e meu {$valor['valor2']} ";`

Comment: Realmente estava precisando desses dois arrays, teria como criar um array multidimensional a partir de dois arrays diferentes?

Comment: Tem sim com array_combine, respondi a pergunta mostrando um exemplo.

Comment: Dei um edit na pergunta, ambos arrays podem ter X elementos, que são definidos pelo $cc, tinha colocado daquele modo apenas para simplificar a mesma, att

Comment: Eu entendo mas o que está confuso é a sua frase `Esse é meu valor1 e meu valor2`, pq na frase vc procura apenas pelos valores 1 e 2, e se o array tiver valor 3, valor 4 muito mais como vc quer q seja exibido na tela?? , Pelo que entendi o array $nome seria o nome das chaves q irá buscar pelos valores que estiverem na mesma posição da variavel $valor correto??

Comment: Também não entendi, só o `str_replace()` não resolve? ex: `$z = str_replace($nome, $valor, $x);
echo $z;`

Comment: É q não tem muita logica, pq os dois arrays podem ser dinamicos, mas a frase so pede 2 valores. Eu editei a minha resposta, colocando mais valores de exemplo.

Comment: Me desculpem por não ter sido mais claro na questão, espero que a definição no edit 2 ajude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está criando um array de strings diferentes em `$string`.

Você pode consertar isso utilizando só uma variável, no caso usei o próprio `$x`:

```
$valor = array('1', '2');
$nome = array('valor1', 'valor2');
$x = "Esse é meu valor1 e meu valor2";
for ($i = 0; $i < $cc; $i++) {
    $x = str_replace($nome[$i], $valor[$i], $x);
}
echo $x; //Saída: "Esse é meu 1 e meu 2"
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/B1yfwH).

**Algumas considerações:**

- Você estava dando `echo` dentro do `for`, por isso aparecia 2 strings.
- Você estava utilizando `++$i` ao invés de `$i++`, não é errado, mas foge do padrão.

Comment: Boa tarde Francisco, tentei desse jeito antes já, o problema é que ele salva apenas o ultimo valor , no caso "Esse é meu valor1 e meu 2", teria algum jeito  de alterar os dois valores na mesma string apartir dos arrays?  Grato pela resposta e considerações

Comment: @viniciusmartin Você testou o código que eu deixei? Aqui funciona exatamente do jeito que você quer.

Comment: Sim, essa solução foi a primeira que pensei, mas estava apenas imprimindo a ultima opção após percorrer o array, eu fiz umas alteraçoes na pergunta que podem ajudar a ver o problema que estou tendo ; )

Comment: @viniciusmartin Da uma [o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpAu95MjO0I)lhada [aqui](https://imgur.com/a/Tu9AB).

Comment: Sim, mas aqui ele pega o ultimo valor apenas, @Francisco olha so https://paste.ofcode.org/UnbrtXVGFE75N6QzizXbuM

Comment: @viniciusmartin Psé, mas você não está fazendo o que eu falei. Você ta criando um array, no meu exemplo eu estou criando uma string.

Comment: Não acredito, muito obrigado de coração, eu tava errando um pequeno detalhe ahaha, obrigado pela resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

Acho q vc poderia utilizar um array multidimensional para resolver esse caso, mas se vc não puder, talvez um array_combine tbm daria certo:

```
 $valor = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
 $nome = array('valor1', 'valor2', 'valr3', 'vl4', 'v5');
 $valores = array_combine($nome, $valor);

echo "Esse é meu {$valores['valor1']} e meu {$valores['valor2']}, mas tenho também o {$valores['valr3']}, junto com {$valores['vl4']} e {$valores['v5']}";
```

Nem iria precisar do loop. Agora se vc for ter mais valores, de uma editada na sua pergunta colocando mais detalhes.